# Symfony API transforming date

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, symfony-forms

I'm making an API with Symfony 4 and I'm trying to get it to accept a date, but it keeps throwing the `Unable to transform data for property path "dateofbirth": Expected a string.` error.

Field in entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateofbirth;
```

Field in Form:

```php
->add('dateofbirth', DateType::class, [
    'html5' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'input' => 'string',
    'input_format' => 'Y-m-d'
])
```

Now if I send it JSON with `"dateofbirth": "1990-02-12"` for example, it throws that error. I've also tried sending something like `"dateofbirth": "1990-02-12T00:00:00+01:00"` with the `'input_format'` set to `Y-m-d\TH:i:sP`, but I get the same issue.

I've been messing around with the options array for a while now and I've also tried configurations other than the one above, but that's what I have right now. Instead of listing all the ones I've tried that didn't work, I hope someone can just tell me what does.

Comment: Shoudn't `DateType` be `DateTime`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly `DateType` is a class intended for Symfony forms. See [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/forms.html) and [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/date.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [`DateType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#input) documentation:

> **input**
>
> The format of the input data - i.e. the format that the date is stored
> on your underlying object.

Since you have declared your entity as `@Column(type="date")` you should set `input` to `datetime`. Symfony will create the object according to the `input_format` and map it to the model.

And since you are sending a single field, set `widget` to `single_text`, as the default value of [`choice`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#widget) will expect an object with `day, month, year`.

Comment: This brings me back to the error I was struggling with in the first place; `ERROR: This value is not valid`. I thought the more descriptive error might have been a sign of moving in the right direction, but I suppose it wasn't. Thank you for your answer, if you have any of how to fix the other error, please let me know.

Comment: @Luctia - Try adding 'widget' => 'single_text' to the form element options